# Bootstrap image on right with max width

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I want my image to be right-aligned. So I did this:

```css
.section {
    margin-bottom: var(--double-margin);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="rounded float-right w-50" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x200.jpg"/>
           </div>          

           <div class="col">
               <p>So other text</p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the result, my image went on the left (because of w-50). So how to tell my image that it should be 50% width and aligned to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example and it works fine. You either need to add a reproducible example of your problem or find the difference between your code and my example. I can guess that for some reason your .col does not grow to 100% of the width that's why the image is aligned to the right side of the smaller container and for you, it looks like it's aligned to left.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col">
    <img class="rounded float-right w-50" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x200.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @AdamJachocki well, the first problem is that your float is not working as in Bootstrap 5 positions renamed from left/right to start/end. Use `float-end` class to align the image to the right side of the container. Also, what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want the text to wrap around the image?

Comment: @AdamJachocki Glad that it helps, you can also add `text-end` class to image `col`, that way you will not need to use floats which are designed for a bit different purposes :)